# Anomaly detection in Text Classification

Tags: nlp, word2vec, outliers, anomaly-detection

I have built a text classifier using OneClassSVM.

I have the training set which corresponds to only one label i.e("Yes") and I don't have the other("NO") label data. My task is to build a classifier which classifies the new unseen sentence(test data) as 1 if it is very similar to the training data. Else, it classifies as -1 i.e,(anomaly).

I have used Word2Vec to build the word embeddings for my training data. Then, I am using word-vector averaging with OneClassSVM to build a anomaly detector classifier.

This classifier is currently giving accuracy of about 50%-55%. I have to enhance this further to build a robust classifier.

Any suggestions to this problem would be helpful...

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest a very different approach since you have no training examples for the negative class at all.
You could train a language model on your training data. At inference time, you score the input with the language model, and classify it according to some threshold on the perplexity of the input sentence according to the LM.